# How to sort a 2-D array by the values of any specific key in PHP alphabetically?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got a multidimensional array that I want to sort alphabetically by the values of specific key. Structure of the array is -

```
Array
(
    [sr] => Array
        (
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 6
            [8] => 7
            [9] => 8
            [10] => 9
        )
 [deptt] => Array
        (
            [2] => KKT-TICKETING
            [3] => KKT-TICKETING
            [4] => KKT-TICKETING
            [5] => KKT-HOTELS
            [6] => KKT-TICKETING
            [7] => KKT-HOTELS
            [8] => GTT-TICKETING
            [9] => GTT-HOTELS
            [10] => GTT-TICKETING
        )
```

I wanted to sort the data on basis of key 'deptt' alphabetically by the values. My desired output should be like all 'GTT-HOTELS' data should shown first then 'KKT-HOTELS' -

```
 [deptt] => Array
        (
            [2] => GTT-HOTELS
            [3] => GTT-TICKETING
            [4] => GTT-TICKETING
            [5] => KKT-HOTELS
            [6] => KKT-HOTELS
            [7] => KKT-TICKETING
            [8] => KKT-TICKETING
            [9] => KKT-TICKETING
            [10] => KKT-TICKETING
        )
with corresponding values of key 'sr'.
```

Any ideas how to do this? Hope I could make you understand the scenario.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried usort()? I presume even a simple asort() function would do.

Comment: I don't understand the logic for reassigning keys. How does `[9] => GTT-HOTELS` transform to `[2] => GTT-HOTELS`? Also, why are there two `KKT-HOTELS` values in the source but three in the destination?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort

Comment: I have tried almost all sorting advised in different threads here like  ksort, usort, multisort but I think I am using it incorrectly. Please help me with the code. @Chris I have corrected the output, sorry for this.

Comment: Okay, is this correct? The _values_ of the `sr` array can be thrown away, and the _keys_ of the `deptt` array can as well? Then sort the `deptt` array alphabetically, and finally apply the keys from the `sr` array to the `deptt` array. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Chris Yes this is correct. Exactly, i wanted to do same, but i couldn't do it. Tried this - 

**array_multisort(array_column($body, 'lob'), SORT_DESC, $body); **

but didn't work. It will be great help if you could share me the code to do this. Will be learning for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this data:

```php
$data = [
    'sr' =>
        [
            2 => 1,
            3 => 2,
            4 => 3,
            5 => 4,
            6 => 5,
            7 => 6,
            8 => 7,
            9 => 8,
            10 => 9,
        ],
    'deptt' =>
        [
            2 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
            3 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
            4 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
            5 => 'KKT-HOTELS',
            6 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
            7 => 'KKT-HOTELS',
            8 => 'GTT-TICKETING',
            9 => 'GTT-HOTELS',
            10 => 'GTT-TICKETING',
        ]
];
```

The below code can be used. The magic is in the [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function which merges two arrays, using one for the keys and one for the values. However, in both cases, it takes the *values* of those arrays, so you need to call `array_keys` on the former to get those as values.

```php
// Grab our arrays as variables
$sr = $data['sr'];
$deptt = $data['deptt'];

// Sort the latter by values alphabetically
sort($deptt);

// Merge them together, keys from the first and values from the second
$final = array_combine(array_keys($sr), $deptt);
```

This produces the following:

```php
array (
  2 => 'GTT-HOTELS',
  3 => 'GTT-TICKETING',
  4 => 'GTT-TICKETING',
  5 => 'KKT-HOTELS',
  6 => 'KKT-HOTELS',
  7 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
  8 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
  9 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
  10 => 'KKT-TICKETING',
)
```

Additional care should be taken to make sure that both arrays have the same number of items. `array_combine` will return false in that case.